# Problem on creating postgres stored procedure | Postgres 12

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm kinda new on Postgres, so I need your help for this one.

```
postgres=# select version();
                          version
------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

---

```
1. CREATE PROCEDURE test (INT,varchar(200))
2. LANGUAGE plpgsql    
3. AS $$
4. BEGIN
5.
6.  create table test1 as
7.  select id,name from mst_user_mobile limit 5
8.
9.    COMMIT;
10. END;
11. $$;
```

From what I read, Postgres version above 10, support PROCEDURE method. But when I execute the code it always error on line 1 (on word PROCEDURE)

here error that i got:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"
LINE 1: CREATE PROCEDURE test (INT,varchar(200))
               ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 8
```

any helps are welcome

Comment: What is the full error message  ? I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the **complete** error message you get ([edit] your question do not put additional information into comments)

Comment: Terminate the `create table` statement with a semicolon (`;`): `... limit 5;`. If there are more problems, come back with the full error message.

Comment: I already add the semicolon, but still have same issues.

I add some details above, hope you can help me. thanks.

Comment: This [works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0319b6c07470dd5b6effced7c2de2e64) there must be something else you are not telling us. Btw: you should give your parameter names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You report to be using Postgres 12.3. Yet, the reported error message is *exactly* what I see in Postgres 10 (or older):

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"
> LINE 1: CREATE PROCEDURE test (INT,varchar(200))
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=421683b6d0cb9fece4b184c455895641)*

[`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) was introduced with Postgres 11.
I suspect you are connected to the wrong / a different database.

All that aside, your example could just be a [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html). The `COMMIT` is pointless as last command. See:

- [In PostgreSQL, what is the difference between a “Stored Procedure” and other types of functions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194811/3684)

**Or**, it's another **missing semicolon** before the `CREATE PROCEDURE` command. (You show another one of those in the question.) I can reproduce the error message this way, too:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b2a0bfadeb9c10dddc89c94a30dbd0a8)*

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem are the `;` on `END` and the last `$$`. You shouldn't use them in this cases!